# MVC data annotation and un obtrusive javascript

Tags: model-view-controller, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

Could somebody please let me know if using data annotation for client side validation makes any difference in performance ( i.e. takes more time to load the page)? especially if it is quite a big page with loads of validation passed from model.

obviously these 2 attributes needs to be true in web.config to get that working.. 
EnableClientValidation
EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think for the client side validation you have to use java script. it's take less time to load.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! so you are saying that we should not use validation on client side using model data annotation? but then we can have 2 different set of validation which can be inconsistent? is this for sure that delays are quite major which can be seen by the user? when i tried with or without unObtrusive javascript it didn't make any difference in loading!

Comment: Most welcome, there are two types of validation client side validation and server side validation. we can use anything it can be depend on our requirements but in my opinion client side validation is more efficient then server side validation.

Comment: Looks like i am not able to explain well.. what we are doing is validating at both end, server side as well as client side. (because only client side is not enough to check the data consistency!) but obviously for client side validation we are using data annotation attributes of mvc model. so I wanted to know if it effects the performance of the application because ultimately it generates the client side validation using model...

Comment: Client side validations are less secure then server side validation.if you want to use the server side validations you can use because they are secure in every browser.